# Extra mouse in /dev/input

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, thinkpad, mouse-scroll

I have an issue with two-finger scrolling on Google Chrome. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. When scrolling in the browser, the page randomly jumps backwards! I have seen a few similar bugs reported on Google Chrome website. When I digged into the issue, I found that I have 2 mouse devices in my /dev/inputs. mouse0 and mouse1. I am wondering if this is causing the problem. I have not connected any external mouse. I am using a Thinkpad X1. Is it possible that the mouse1 is actually the trackpad?
The issue wasn't there in Ubuntu 14.10.

What is the safest way to disable /dev/input/mouse1 and check if it resolves the problem?